# How can I alias vim only if no filename given?

Tags: shell, vim, command-line

I want to `` alias vim = 'vim -o `fzf`' `` only if no filename provided. How can I do this check? I find a way to check if a command has a parameter or not:

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
  then
    alias vim = 'vim -o `fzf`'
fi
```

but it seems overwhelming, I just want to do this check when using vim.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Define a function

```
function runvim() {
    if [ $# -eq 0 ] 
    then
        command vim -o `fzf`
    else
        command vim "$@"
    fi
}
```

and alias vim to the function

```
alias vim=runvim
```

**Edited** so that the function calls vim using `command` (ensures that the alias does not result in function being called recursively) and to double quote `$@` so command line arguments are parsed correctly.

Comment: If you call the function `vim`, you can forego the alias, but you have to use `command vim` in the body

Comment: Also, need double quotes around `"$@"` for it to work with filenames that include spaces or other shell metacharacters.

Comment: @CR : Wouldn't `vim -o ...` etc. inside the function invoke the _alias_ vim, causing an infinite recursion? In bash or zsh, I would write it as `command vim -o ....`, but I think `command` is not available in POSIX shell; hence in this case, the absolute path to `vim` should be specified.

Comment: @user1934428 POSIX [has `command`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/command.html), so that should be okay.

Comment: @user1934428 Alias names are resolved when the function is read. So long as the function is defined before the alias it won't recurse. But agree it is better to use `command vim` to be on the safe side.

Comment: Thank you for explaining .... one more reason why not to use an alias, as this is not really intuitive.